# Validating complex model in directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

If I have a simple property bound to a control I can easily validate it either using the built-in directives (required, etc) or using ngModel.$validators.

However I have a directive that represents an editor for a complex property.  I can validate the state from within that editor, but how do I integrate that with Angular so that it updates the state of the form?

I have a model class that represents the model and I am calling the directive like this:

```
<editor model="model"></editor>
```

With this code in my controller (appModel has been declared as a service since it is a singleton):

```
$scope.model = appModel;
```

I am thinking of just accessing the form from my directive, taking advantage of the scope inheritance, something like:

```
$scope.myform.$setValidity(...)
```

Is that the normal way to go about it?

Comment: If you use `ngModel` then everything is taken care of for you.

Comment: Do you have an example of using ngModel binding to an object and not a scalar property?  I tried to read $modelValue but it is getting coerced to a string at one point or another.  I need to bind the controls inside of my "editor" directive to properties on the model.

Comment: `$modelValue` can be whatever you like it to be. Any occurring problems would be worth another question. Instead of relying on the scope you should directly access the form controller. See my answer.

Comment: I figured out my problem with $modelValue - it was just a timing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should access the form through the `FormController` by requiring it:

```
module.directive('editor', function() {
  return {
    require: '^form',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) {
            ...
            formCtrl.$setValidity();
```

Comment: I like that, thank you!  Might do some more debugging to understand what is going on with ngModel, if I get the time for it.